# PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, phasset

I am getting a crash in 'fetchAssetsInAssetCollection' with my NSPredicate when attempting to retrieve only assets in a PHAssetCollection with the following predicate:

```
NSMutableArray<PHAssetCollection*>* validCollections = [NSMutableArray array];
PHFetchOptions* options = [PHFetchOptions new];
options.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(mediaType == 1) AND pixelWidth >= (2 * pixelHeight)"];

for (PHAssetCollection* collection in array)
{
    PHFetchResult<PHAsset*>* assets = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:collection options:options];

    if (assets.count > 0)
    {
        [validCollections addObject:collection];
    }
}
```

The message I receive, on an iOS 10 device is:

```
CRASH: Fetch threw on server ({
    "exception info" = {
        "exception name" = NSInvalidArgumentException;
        "exception reason" = "Unsupported function expression 2 * pixelHeight";
    }; 
})
```

According to Apple's documentation, 'pixelHeight' is a valid key. However, this will only work on iOS 10 if I use 'height' instead.

In iOS 9, this crashes outright with the following information:

```
CRASH: *** -constantValue only defined for abstract class.  Define -[NSFunctionExpression constantValue]!
```

Has anyone else run into this, or know a solution to this that works on both iOS 9 & 10?

As of iOS 11, this is still an issue.

Comment: Did you solved it?

Comment: I am also facing this issue

Comment: I haven't been able to solve this, except looking at the assets and culling the list I get back.

Comment: Even I did the same ...but is very time consuming operation for very large photo album